# So I am trying to run a python script on my mac using atom and for some reason it is not working right

Tags: python, terminal, path-finding

it might be a pathing issue since the first error I got on script was the pygame module not existing and after trying to install the module on the terminal i keep getting a DEPRECATION message saying python 2.7 reached the end of it's life.......

I'm trying to figure out how to set my atom text editor path right and figure out how to use pip 3 on the terminal any advice on what to do?

just for context this was all working until sometime ago. I haven't downloaded anything since then.

Comment: That’s right, Python 2 has reached the end of its life this year. You should use Python 3 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have u tried simply uninstalling python and reinstalling the newest version? Had this issue some times when teaching python, and uninstalling + reinstalling plus considering the correct environment variable path ( https://discuss.atom.io/t/running-python-on-atom/49460) solved it always so far, good luck!